# JQuery cookie extension will set a cookie with a path but will not read it

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-cookie, cookie-path

First, set a [cookie](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/cookie):

```
jQuery.cookie('monster', 'big', { path : '/sesame/'});
```

Next, try to read it:

```
jQuery.cookie('monster');
```

Firefox tells me that the cookie has indeed been set. The value is `big` and the path is `/sesame/`. And yet when I tried to read the cookie it wouldn't work.

Alternate version of the question: How do I specify the path when *reading* a cookie?

As an experiment I used the following syntax but it sets a cookie rather than read one.

```
$.cookie('cookie_name', { path: '/path/' });
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JQuery cookie extension searches the `document.cookie` attribute to find a cookie and read its value. `Document.cookie` will only return the name, value pairs for cookies under the *current document path*. It does however allow you to *set* a cookie for a path *different* from the current document path.

Therefore this is not a limitation/bug in the jQuery cookie plugin; rather it is a byproduct of how cookies are handled in Javascript.

Answer (score 7):

Browser will not send cookie to the path its not set to!

Browser sends only cookie name and value. There is no way to find out cookie path or expiration time.

Comment: Can you rephrase it? I am not sure what you mean (given my question).